# Proper alternative for the unreliable Search and Replace of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, plugins, add-in

Today I was actually wondering why I've stuck with it for so many years without actively complaining about it. Doing a *"search & replace in all files and folders of a solution"* is something I quite regularly need to do, esp. when refactoring tools fail me. Unfortunately, *"all folders and files"* means *"some projects and some other files"*. Notably, unconnected files in solution folders, complete web sites and csproj/vbproj/sln files are skipped.

Also, just searching often reveals more hits than replacement replaces (for instance, a csproj is only replaced when its project is unloaded).

Ok, enough complaining: anybody aware of a good plugin or a nice valuable trick that can do a *real* search and replace through all files and folders of a solution? Something I can rely on?

*(edit)

PS: after some more thought: having your system under Subversion or other source control system will make a full search only really valuable when the folder-list could contain a filter of exclusions, i.e., exclude all .svn files and dirs. Unfortunately, as far as I know, that's not possible with the supplied solution.*

Comment: I've used Visual Studio forever, and have never had these problems, at least not since 2002. You're doing something wrong and blaming the tool.

Comment: Possibly. Try this: open a solution that has a web site (mind you: not a web project!) with VB and C# code folders, plus some normal other projects. Select one of the normal projects. Hit Ctrl-Shift-H, select Entire Solution and replace, say, your company name. You'll see that unopened files of the web site will not be replaced. When focus is on the web site, some things are, some things are not replaced. Non code files (txt, log) are usually not searched. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I had this in 2005 and 2008. I consider the S&R a "smart" search (like Windows S&R) being too smart.

Comment: Same issues arise with auto-refactoring method renaming, which is very buggy as well and has ever been, with the exception of C++. The problem is with lazy invocation of methods on untyped variables or where the method names are strings (i.e., quoted events in ASPX/ASCX, reflection etc). I can understand this going wrong, the type system cannot know. But then doing a replace all S&R should fix things, but it doesn't. Most notably with web sites (again: not web projects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not a plugin for Visual Studio [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)'s find (and replace) in files functionality seems to be solid.

You even get syntax highlighting of your code - though not for aspx files by default. However, [this post](http://www.mattblodgett.com/2007/11/notepad-tip-syntax-highlighting-for.html) tells you how to get it working.

**UPDATE**

You can get a more comprehensive search and replace from within Visual Studio.

`Ctrl+Shift+H` to go the the dialog up.

Then select the `...` button next to the "Look in" drop down to get the "Choose Search Folders" dialog.

Pick your folder and then do your search and replace (or just search even).

Comment: Thanks, but several tools (V, UltraEdit, Notepad++, CodeWarrior, even Eclipse) have excellent S&R. I just hoped for something that works from within VS. Maybe I should write a plugin myself? Shouldn't be that hard...

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that. It uses the concept of *folder sets* and if I remember well, it was a nuisance to get it to work, but I might just need to *learn* to use it. If it works and doesn't take the better part of the day to set up, it'd be a good replacement. Note that `*` here searches in the VS installation folder, *not* the current solution or execution folder.

Comment: In a particular use-case scenario it went from 3 matching lines (normal S&R in whole solution) to 22 matching lines using the `...`. I guess that pretty much sums it up ;-). Tx!

Comment: Using the "..." button does the trick, "entire solution" does not work for csproj files.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issues with "Entire Solution".
In fact it is not effectively "entire" and that's the point.
I shouldn't need to learn how to use the tool. Is there a tool for me or am I for the tool?
It is so simple - "entire" means "entire" for me but not for the feature developers.

For now I don't use "Entire Solution" but I replace it with a path every time. It's not perfect because it may search other files in the directory that are outside the solution but it's more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [VS Command Shell](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=VSCmdShell) and let Windows do the walking. Even if you don't use it for S&R, it's nice to have.

Comment: +1 for an interesting idea. It might save me quite some back and forth to the Windows shell that I do nowadays (and findstr wins by far from Windows' own search, which I never understood, but that's another story)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's not the best search tool in the world, but I've never had any of the problems you describe.

You imply that it is not possible to filter the files searched in Visual Studio, and that files on disk that are not referenced in your solution are not searched. Well, that's because you've asked Visual Studio to do that - I think you need to learn how to use the tool better, because it handles these situations perfectly well.

You can set the search to work on a solution, on specific projects, the current project, open documents only, the current document, or search any folder hierarchy on your drive with a list of filename filters to choose precisely what is scanned. These settings can be saved and then used whenever you need them by just choosing the pre-set in a combobox. The user interface for setting this up is pretty awful, but once it's set up it works well. For example, I often use an "entire codebase" to search my drive rather than "Entire Solution" which only searches the files in my solution. Or "All XML files". Or "All Source files but no headers". Etc.

If you have problems with scanning open projects, then don't - just run another instance of VS with no solution loaded in it. The idea of trying to use one instance of VS to handle everything (with all the window layout reconfiguring that is necessary as you swap between tasks) quite frankly baffles me.

Comment: My complaint was about "entire solution" searches, but I didn't realize that when i wrote it. I know of the types of searches (but had forgotten about the arcane method of folder groups). Since I recently work a lot on web sites (not web projects!), the weird thing happens: search "entire solution" replaces less then searching "current project" when the current prj is a web site. My guess is, since a "web site" is not actually a project, it's not correctly searched.

Comment: Quote "quite frankly baffles me.": me too. And it makes it sloooow. Maybe I should more often switch to single-project IDE instances, but I've just gotten used to this...